# If a series is convergent and contains only irrational numbers, does the limit also have to be irrational?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers

I have encountered this problem. If $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is a sequence such that $a_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ for every natural number $n$ and the $l = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is a real number, does that mean that $l \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$? The original question that I have found didn't mention the fact that $l$ is a number and such I was able to provide the series $a_n = (\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3}) ^ n$ which contains only irrational numbers and the limit if $\infty$. But what if the series is convergent?

Comment: What about $a_n = \sqrt[\pi]{2}^{-n}$?

Comment: A sequence of irrational numbers could still converge to something rational.  Take for an easy example the sequence $f(n)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ which clearly converges to $0$ which is rational.  If your question is specifically about series, this can be easily modified so that this sequence is the sequence of partial sums of your series.  $g(1)=\sqrt{2}, g(n)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n-1}$

Comment: You are talking about sequences, not series. Please correct that in your post!

Comment: @ErdelvonMises How do you prove that $\sqrt[\pi]{2}$ is irrationnal ?

Comment: It's difficult to conclude that if $a_n$ is irrational then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\in\mathbb{R-Q}$. If it happens to be true then, Euler mascheroni constant have to be irrational (It's an unsolved problem if it's rational or not).

Comment: @RAHUL "*It is difficult to conclude...*"  You can not conclude that because it is false, as proven by the counterexample in my first comment......  There exist sequences of irrational numbers whose limit is irrational.  There exist sequences of irrational numbers whose limit is rational.  There exist sequences of rational numbers whose limit is irrational.  There exist sequences of rational numbers whose limit is rational.  You can not assume anything about the rationality of the limit of a sequence based on the rationality of the terms of the sequence.

Comment: As a rule, try not to use *sequence* and *series* interchangeably.  Stick to *sequence* when you have an infinite *list* of numbers, and reserve *series* for when you add them up.